# How to get a of count of items for multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have multiple tables (one for each day) that all have the same structure: ID, srcIP, time.

I can get the total rows for each day using the following:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Day1) as Day1Count, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Day2) as Day2Count,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Day3) as Day3Count
```

But that just gives me

```
Day1count  Day1count Day1count
102        148       131
```

But how can I get a total count for each IP address per day? Not all IPs are present every day.

```
srcIP       D1  D2  D3
172.16.0.1      99  34
172.16.0.2  55      22
172.16.0.3  47  49  75
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `Day1` contain day-1 logs for every month?

Comment: yes, just three fields: ID, srcIP, & time.

Comment: no, each month is a database and each table is a day

Comment: Your database seems **cryptic** could you demystify it for us ?

Comment: sure, each time a computer connects, the connection is logged along with the data. So really there are 4 fields, but the 4th does not interest me because it has a huge amount of info & I just want to know how often an IP is connecting each day for the month.

Comment: I just saw there was a typo in my first post that caused the confusion, sorry about that. I changed it now.

Comment: If you go with a single table with a timestamp, which seems sensible, try to include an overnight archiving policy as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get counts by ip and by day, the easiest way is to flatten the query:

```
SELECT 'day1' AS day, srcIP, count(*) AS count FROM Day1 GROUP BY srcIP
UNION
SELECT 'day2' AS day, srcIP, count(*) AS count FROM Day2 GROUP BY srcIP
UNION
SELECT 'day3' AS day, srcIP, count(*) AS count FROM Day3 GROUP BY srcIP
```

and then transpose it in your app to get the table format you want.

**Alternatively**

You can also do it by joining on IP:

```
SELECT srcIP, d1.count, d2.count, d3.count
FROM (SELECT srcIP, count(*) AS count FROM Day1 GROUP BY srcIP) d1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT srcIP, count(*) AS count FROM Day2 GROUP BY srcIP) d2 USING (srcIP)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT srcIP, count(*) AS count FROM Day3 GROUP BY srcIP) d3 USING (srcIP)
```

But here you will be missing IPs that are not in Day1, unless you first do a SELECT DISTINCT srcIP from a UNION of all days, which is pretty expensive.  Basically this table structure doesn't lend itself too easily to this kind of aggregation.

Comment: that was the best I could come up with, because there are about 200,000 entries per day. Do you have any better ideas for a structure?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried it, but it didn't make a column for each day. I only produced a list of ips & counts.

Comment: Normally you would just have a single table with columns for month and day (or a timestamp). Look at [table paritioning](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_5.1_partitions.html) if you want to optimize for data access by month.

Comment: This would have better been done with a single table, but the solution is outsmarts the weirdness of the problem; +1 for that :)